# Git - Issuing A Pull Request To Another Repo In The Same Organization

Tags: git, github, pull

Here is the situation I am trying to resolve:

I have an organization with two separate repositories.

Repo A is a fork of an external branch from somewhere outside of the organization.

My objective is to issue a Pull Request to the main branch of Repo B (in same organization as Repo A) from the main branch of Repo A.

I am not seeing a way to do this -- when I open the new pull request, the only option that I have for the Base or Head repository are Repo B and the Repo that I forked from.

Can anybody help?

I have tried opening a new PR, and the reason that I went about it this way is because I keep getting errors when trying to switch my remote origin to the main branch in the organization's Repo B (See above), so I ended up with this mess and now I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can only open a pull request against another branch in the same repository, or against a branch in the upstream repository from which your repository was forked. Because Repo B is neither of those things, you won't be able to open a GitHub pull request against it.

> I keep getting errors when trying to switch my remote origin to the main branch in the organization's Repo B

It might help to see those error messages. In general, what you probably want to do with your local repository is:

- Add Repo B as a *new* upstream remote
- Rebase your changes on top of the appropriate branch in Repo B. This may involve resolving conflicts if Repo B has diverged significantly from the point at which you branched your changes.
- Push your changes to Repo B
- Open a pull request with your changes in Repo B

If you're not able to push your changes to a branch in Repo B (i.e., you don't have appropriate access), you can create a new fork of Repo B (possibly replacing your Repo A), push your changes there, and then open a pull request against Repo B.

Comment: Thanks, I follow what you're saying, and that's what I tried first -- here's my problem and how I ended up trying to do this:

When I run git remote -v to see my current remote, I get the current origin. This origin is in a branch of the Organization's repo that I am ultimately trying to push my local work to. (I didn't clone from anywhere). 

When I try git push origin <branc_name>, I get:

error: src refspec <name> does not match any

I am staring at the name in the return from git remote -v right now, so I really don't understand this.

Comment: When I try anything else for the name (the URL, etc.) I get an invalid respec. 

So, I've tried to change the origin to the main branch, and I think I'm following the exact instructions and commands to do it but those don't work either. Hence, I've ended up trying this roundabout method. 

Honestly, all I need to do is commit of files in to any of repo's branches and then I can issue a pull request to the main branch. I really don't understand why this is so difficult. 

I'm not able to manually upload the folder with the files to GitHub either, or else I would just do that.

Comment: The error `src refspec <name> does not match any` is an error about *local* branches (it's saying you don't have a local branch `<name>`). If you are trying to rename a branch (e.g., push local branch `main` to remote branch `foo`), you can run something like `git push origin main:foo`.

Comment: Ty, when you're saying to add Repo B as a new upstream remote, you're saying to run git remote -set--url origin for the branch of Repo B that I want to push to right?

Comment: By "adding a new upstream remote", I mean rather than *replacing* `origin` (because maybe will need it in the future?), create a new remote (`git remote add <name> <url>`), but if you don't need to preserve the existing `origin` then running `git remote set-url origin <url>` is accomplishing pretty much the same thing.

Comment: What seems to the root of all these issues is that I'm not able to set a new remote origin to push to. If I was able to do that, then I could just push there.

Comment: Ah, okay I'm trying git remote add right now, will report back in a moment.

Comment: Okay added!!!! Attempting to push now.

Comment: I ran git remote add target <repo_URL> 

That worked! git remote -v now shows the URL under the alias of: target

When I run git push -u target <branch_name> , I get another refspec error saying "<branch_name> does not match any"

Comment: I am working in a local copy of a different repo (I ran git init for the local files and now I am trying push them the remote branch of a different repo that I also have access to.) 

Maybe this is the problem. git branch returns:

 */master

    git remote -v:

origin <URL of a branch on the target repo> (fetch)
origin <URL of same branch as first row> (fetch)
target <URL of the target Repo itself> (fetch)
target <URL of the target repo itself> (push>